# Android Room - Relationship With Constraints

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have the following relations setup in a database
[image]

I would like to select every user that has at least one time for a particular job, with that time. We are using the Android Room sqlite wrapper.

---

### What I have tried so far

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN times ON times.userId = users.id WHERE (times.jobId = :job)")
fun all(job: Long): LiveData<List<UserWithTime>>
```

And UserWithTime is

```
data class UserWithTime(
    @Embedded
    val user: User
) {

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "userId", entity = Time::class)
    lateinit var times: List<Time>
}
```

---

This setup returns each user each repeated several times identically

The times attached to each object have not been selected for the particular job, but are every time the user has.

---

The crux of my question is how can I select relations in Android Room with an added constraints on this relation